# Mysql export resultset as CSV from remote server

Tags: mysql

My application runs on server 1 and DB is on server 2.I want to get the output of select query as a CSV to server 1 i.e. my application server.How can I achieve this.
Select into outfile wont help because it dumps only on the local server so if I run query on DB server it would create the file on it not the application server.
mysql -e option also doesent help because it does not dump as CSV.
Could anyone suggest how to directly create file locally as CSV from remote server?
Thanks.

Comment: Actually I am also having the same scenario as you explained, I gone through the answer, still I am interested to in solution that you have actually implemented, whats experience?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use `outfile` and afterwards ftp the file to the local host or pass the result of a normal query to some sed/awk to convert it to csv?

What I found is:
`` mysql -umysqlusername -pmysqlpass databasename -B -e "select * from \`tablename\`;" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > mysql_exported_table.csv ``

Besides that, we're going with the (s)ftp solution.

Comment: Or run mysql where you want the CSV file and connect using '-h yourdb.example.com' (assuming that it's directly accessible)

Comment: @symcbean Connecting to a remote server with `-h` still writes the file to the remote DB server if you use the typical `SELECT... INTO OUTFILE` method.

Comment: @mitsy: If you run the command as shown above, the file will be created on the client.

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of the MySQL clients (tested on 14.14) on Linux use tab delimiters by default when redirecting stdout to a file:

```
mysql -h serverhostname -uuserid -ppassword databasename -e 'select * from mytbale order by update_ts desc' >output.tsv
```

Most apps that accept csv will accept tsv, or you should be able to convert easily yourself, see [How do I convert a .tsv to .csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759305/how-do-i-convert-a-tsv-to-csv).