# TSV to CSV convert Python

Tags: python, csv, type-conversion

I want to convert this file.tsv to csv 
the conversion works well but the seperation of the fields isn't 
this is the file.tsv

```
protein1 protein2 neighborhood neighborhood_transferred fusion cooccurence homology coexpression coexpression_transferred experiments experiments_transferred database database_transferred textmining textmining_transferred combined_score
9606.ENSP00000003084 9606.ENSP00000301645 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 163 129 239
```

here is the first line result file.csv

```
"protein1 protein2 neighborhood neighborhood_transferred fusion cooccurence homology coexpression coexpression_transferred experiments experiments_transferred database database_transferred textmining textmining_transferred combined_score"
"9606.ENSP00000003084 9606.ENSP00000301645 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 163 129 239"
```

Here is the code

```
import csv


print(csv.list_dialects())


with open('File.tsv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as fin, \
     open('file2.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as fout: 

     reader = csv.reader(fin, dialect='excel-tab')
     writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=' ')    

     for row in reader:
         writer.writerow(row)
```

The problem is that the code don't seperate the fields using the space, it taked the whole header for one row
  The desired result is that the seperation should be where I put commas
protein1,protein2,neighborhood,neighborhood_transferred,fusion,cooccurence homology,coexpression,coexpression_transferred,experiments experiments_transferred,database,database_transferred,textmining, textmining_transferred,combined_score
9606.ENSP00000003084,9606.ENSP00000301645,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,163,129,239

Comment: show the desired result

Comment: Really this is a futile excercise. CSV readers in most languages can read the data regarldess of whether you use a space or tab as the delimiter

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759305/how-do-i-convert-a-tsv-to-csv

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  I edited the question

Comment: @e4c5 opening it with excel, and as it is a large size of about 700M it is not fully opened , and I need the file to be cnverted for another work

Comment: whether it's space or tab excel will still face the same problem. Your code wouldn't mind either delimiter.

Comment: @e4c5 what could be the solution then

Comment: You haven't mentioned what the problem is. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @e4c5 The problem is that the code do not seperate the attributes it takes the whole header for one row , yet I need it to seperate it where the space is

Answer (score 0):

Edit: answer rewritten after exchange of comments with OP.

The input is specified to expect tabs in the input as delimiters:

```
reader = csv.reader(fin, dialect='excel-tab')
```

but there aren't tabs, there are spaces, so:

```
reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=' ')
```

Note that this will treat 2 consecutive spaces as two delimiters with a null field between them. You can't specify *ignore duplicate delimiters* the way you can in Excel.

Comment: No  That was an example of where I want the separation to be . the probleme is in the starting input file the code do not seperate it  with space

Comment: OK, but if there are spaces in the header line, and not tabs, then `csv.reader` won't split them up because the input dialect is specified as `'excel-tab'`. Are you saying that the header line is space-delimited but the data lines are tab-delimited?

Comment: No the  whole data is space delimited, so  I guess we need to change the dialect to something else right?