# Converting multiple .csv files from semicolon separated to column formatted

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write a code which takes all the .csv files in a directory, which are semi colon delimited, and formats the .csv file into columns. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = r'C:...'
csv_file = path + "\*.csv"
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "\*.csv")

for file in allFiles:
 dataframe = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=';')
 dataframe.to_csv(file, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

I have tested the dataframe = part of this code, it works as desired for one .csv file, but I cannot get this to repeat for all files in the folder. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "column formatted"? Can you edit the question and add example of how you expect the output to be?

Comment: So you want to convert this CSV file into a TSV file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49786129/2308683 -- just change the separator

Comment: Otherwise, [edit] your question to include some code that you've tried after reading the examples here. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Convert csv to xlsx? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17684679/9144250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("csv_semicolon.csv", delimiter=";")
df1.to_csv("csv_tab.csv", sep="\t", index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is change `;` to `,` in the files, something like this would work:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/dirname/"):
    csv_files = [ff for ff in files if ff.endswith('.csv')]
    for f in csv_files:
        with open(f) as tf:
            s = f.read()
        with open(f, "w") as tf:
            f.write(s.replace(";", ","))
```